# How to get a tr value with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing this example to return a tr value in Jquery but it dosen't work this the example.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 1;
  $("tr").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var num = $(this).attr('value');
      if(i == 1)
      {
        $(".informations"+num).show('slow');
        i = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        $(".informations"+num).hide('slow');
        i = 1;
      }
      console.log(num);
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<tr class="informations1 informations" value="1">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
```

Any idea why ? Thanks

Comment: `value="1"` what it does?

Comment: `tr` does not support a value attribute. What are you trying to do?

Comment: instead of using value, can you use custom data-attribute? like `data-value`

Comment: @EvanKnowles it's work Evan you can try it

Answer (score 1):

As `TR` doesn't have value property. I would suggest you to use `data-*` custom attribute.

*HTML*

```
<tr class="informations1 informations" data-value="1">
```

*Script*, You can use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to manipulate it. It also take care of data-type.

```
var num = $(this).data('value');
```

Comment: @Satpal: but his is working . see here. he can get tr value.
http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/yjTuM/

Comment: @AmitKumar, Check http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/j4kub/ I have just use `===` instead of `==` on strict checking it fails. Same fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/jvz3y/ with `.data()` example

Comment: @Satpal wath does it mean === ?

Comment: @KarimEnnassiri, The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except __no type conversion is done__, and the __types__ must be the same to be considered equal. Read [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 1):

use `.toggle()` in jquery

```
$("tr").click(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      var num = $(this).data('value');
      $(".informations"+num).toggle('slow');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr` shouldn't have a `value` attribute. Use `data-value="1"` in HTML and `$(this).data('value');` in code.

**HTML**

```
<tr class="informations1 informations" data-value="1">
```

**JavaScript**

```
...
var num = $(this).data('value');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Value isn't [Attribute W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) for tr tag. Use [data-attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

```
$("tr").click(function(e){
    // ...
    console.log($(this).attr('data-value'));
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table does not have a `<table>` wrapper, that could be your issue. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wJ3CK/. My guess is that you have invalid markup, so the text is being inserted into the DOM without structure (then your binds will be invalid).